# Linked List reversal in C not working

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to do some operations with linked list in C. I have wrote some functions for this like - Insert at beginning, Insert at tail, Delete from beginning etc. In my code I tried to implement reversal of linked list. But it is not working as expected. It always print only first value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
}*new_node,*ptr,*head = NULL,*tmp;

void create_list(int data)
{
    new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head = new_node;
    new_node->link=NULL;
    new_node->data=data;
}

void insert_beginning(int data)
{

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        create_list(data);
    }
    else
    {
        new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->link = head;
        new_node->data=data;
        head=new_node;
    }
}
void insert_tail(int data)
{
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        create_list(data);
    }
    else
    {
        new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        ptr = head;
        while(ptr->link!=NULL)
        {
            ptr=ptr->link;
        }
        new_node->link = NULL;
        new_node->data=data;
        ptr->link=new_node;
    }
}
void insert_any_position(int data)
{
    int pos;
    printf("\nEnter the position: ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    if(pos==1)
    {
        insert_beginning(data);
    }
    else
    {
        int i=1;
        new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        ptr = head;
        while(ptr->link!=NULL&&i<(pos-1))
        {
            ptr=ptr->link;
            i++;
        }
        new_node->link = ptr->link;
        new_node->data=data;
        ptr->link=new_node;
    }
}
void insert_node()
{
    int choice,data;
    printf("\n1.Insert at beginning\n2.Insert at tail\n3.Insert at any position\n4.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if(choice<4)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the data to be inserted: ");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            insert_beginning(data);
            break;
        case 2:
            insert_tail(data);
            break;
        case 3:
            insert_any_position(data);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
    }
    else
        return;

}

void delete_beginning()
{
    head = head->link;
}

void delete_tail()
{
    ptr=head;
    while(ptr->link!=NULL)
    {
        tmp=ptr;
        ptr=ptr->link;
    }
    tmp->link=NULL;
}
void delete_any_position()
{   int pos;
    printf("\nEnter the position: ");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    if(pos==1)
    {
        delete_beginning();
    }
    else
    {
        ptr=head;
        int i=1;
        while(ptr->link!=NULL && i<(pos-1))
        {
            ptr=ptr->link;
            i++;
        }
        ptr->link=(ptr->link)->link;
    }

}
void delete_data()
{

}

void delete_node()
{
    int choice,data;
    printf("\n1.Delete from beginning\n2.Delete from tail\n3.Delete from any position\n4.Delete data\n5.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if(choice<5)
    {

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            delete_beginning();
            break;
        case 2:
            delete_tail();
            break;
        case 3:
            delete_any_position();
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\nEnter the data to be deleted: ");
            scanf("%d",&data);
            delete_data(data);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
    }
    else
        return;
}
void display_list()
{
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
}

void display_list_recursion(struct node* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);
        display_list_recursion(ptr->link);
    }
}
void display_list_recursion_reverse(struct node* ptr)
{
    if(ptr==NULL)
        return;
    else    
    {
        display_list_recursion_reverse(ptr->link);
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);
    }   

}
```

This is the function that is not working:

```
void reverse_list_iteration()
{
    struct node *current,*prev,*next;
    current=head;
    prev=NULL;
    while(current->link!=NULL)
    {
        next = current->link;
        current->link = prev;
        prev=current;
        current=next;
    }
    head=prev;
}

main()
{
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter your choice\n1.Insert\n2.Delete\n3.Display\n4.Display using recursion");
        printf("\n5.Display Reverse\n6.ReverseListIteration\n7.Exit\n\t\t\t");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            insert_node();
            break;
        case 2:
            delete_node();
            break;
        case 3:
            display_list();
            break;
        case 4:display_list_recursion(head);
            break;
        case 5:display_list_recursion_reverse(head);
            break;
        case 6:reverse_list_iteration();
            break;
        case 7:
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    while(choice<7);
}
```

Other functions are working. After calling `reverse_list_iteration()` then calling `display_list()` it displays only one data. I think some links are broken, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is there some classroom rule about only using globals that you're restricted by, because it is quite literally the exact *opposite* you should be striving for.

Comment: try `reverse_list_iteration` when the list contains just one element. Fix that first.

Comment: Don't create `new_node` as a global variable; it should be local in each function.  Avoid global variables whenever possible.  Also, you should adhere to at least C99 and preferably C11, and that means you need an explicit return type on `int main()` — or, preferably, `int main(void)` though both work and are essentially equivalent.  It's also a good idea to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  What you've got is rather complete, but not minimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `current->link!=NULL` to `current!=NULL` in `reverse_list_iteration()` and your problem is solved.

Hope it helps you. Happy coding.

Comment: i tested chux's fix and can confirm it works. One thing I used to find helpful when debugging linked lists was to print the pointer addresses. For Sarath's question i tried this modification to the function named display_list() ----`printf("head:%p\n",head);
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("node:%p link:%p data:%d \n",ptr,ptr->link,ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }`

Comment: @donbright i tried it,yes it helps to debug the linked list and its nice to observe the links changing after reversing the list.